# Angular 2 router navigate not working 2nd time with the same url

Tags: angular, routes

I have a page where on clicking a button, it will redirect using below router navigation

```
router.navigate (['search', {data: 'test'}]).
```

But when I click the same button on 2nd time without changes the values, the router.navigate won't work. How can I override that.

All thoughts are welcome!

Comment: any errors in the browser console? update the post with some code to help

Comment: Angular 2 router works in that way, so if you navigate to the same router it wont refresh it. Do you pass any new params? @Prats

Comment: it will not refresh as the currently activeLink has the same route signature

Comment: You can try  APP_INITIALIZER in app.module so you can refresh the activeLink

Answer (score 7):

```
 this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function(){
        return false;
    };

    this._router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
        if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this._router.navigated = false;
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });
```

I added this to my **app.component.ts** `ngOnInit` function, and it worked fine. All further clicks on the same link now reloads the `component` and data.

[Link to original GitHub feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831)

Credit goes to **mihaicux2** on GitHub.

I tested this on version `4.0.0-rc.3` with `import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';`

Answer (score 5):

Angular router works this way, so if the activeRoute doesn't changed than the page/component won't be loaded again.

If you are passing parameters, like in your example: {data: 'test'} then you can watch these parameters changes by subscribing to route params:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     // each time the search data is change you'll get this running
     //Do what ever you need to refresh your search page
     console.log('New route params');
   });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue in Angular 9 application. The following worked for me

```js
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paramSub = this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => (this.Id = parseInt(params['Id']))
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.paramSub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps provide context and makes your answer much more useful to future readers.