# Html is not getting updated when the model value changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

In my current project, it is required to take a single component to display values from different tables depending on the menu item click.

I am using Observable and the same component for both **Units** and **Colors** module.

**1)** Here in 1st ss if I click on Units first it works fine and binds the correct data in the grid.
[image]

**2)** In 2nd if I click on Colors the grid data should be updated. But it is not updating or even not calling the controller or API calls to server.
[image]

Already Tried: implemented changeDetectorRef and ngDoCheck thing but no luck.

Here's my code **for component**:

```js
export class ListMasterMainComponent implements OnInit
{
    masterModels: MasterMainModel[];
    masterModel = new MasterMainModel();
    errorMessage: string;
    url: string;
    @Input() message: string;
    previous;
    constructor(private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private data: DataService, private el: ElementRef, private router: Router, private MasterMainService: MasterMainService) { }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.previous = this.message;
        this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
        /* Message field will be changed according to selected menu Units in case of 
        Units and Colors in case of Colors.*/
        this.fetchData();
    }

    ngDoCheck()
    {
        if (this.previous !== this.message)
        {
            this._ref.detectChanges();
        }
    }

    onClickAddMasterMain(moduleText)
    {
        this.data.changeMessage(moduleText)
        this._ref.detectChanges();
        const url = this.el.nativeElement.href;
        this.router.navigate(['/addeditmaster'], {
            skipLocationChange: true,
        })
    }

    fetchData(): void
    {
        this.MasterMainService.getDataWithObservable()
            .subscribe(masterModels => this.masterModels = masterModels,
                error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }
}
```

**For Menu Item Click**:

```js
onClickMainMasters(message)
{
    this.data.changeMessage(message)

    switch (this.message)
    {
        case 'Colors':
        this.data.changeUrl('http://localhost:64599/api/Colors');
        this.data.currentUrl.subscribe(url =>this.url=url)
          this.router.navigate(['/listmaster'], {
            skipLocationChange: true,
        });

        event.preventDefault();
        break
        case 'Units':
        this.data.changeUrl('http://localhost:64599/api/Units');
        this.data.currentUrl.subscribe(url =>this.url=url)
          this.router.navigate(['/listmaster'], {
            skipLocationChange: true,
        });
        event.preventDefault();
        break
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What table are you using? Is this something you've built or a library like angular material, or ngx-datatable?

Comment: its simple html table built on bootstrap4 @rrd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you're navigating to the same url/component `/listmaster` again, but if the activeRoute doesn't change, the component won't be reloaded. If displaying the correct data depends on your `fechtData()` function called in the `ngOnInit` of your `ListMasterMainComponent` you have to make sure that this component is instanciated again or call `fetchData()` again at some other place.

Checkout this Question: [Angular 2 router navigate not working 2nd time with the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386595/angular-2-router-navigate-not-working-2nd-time-with-the-same-url/51540703#51540703)

And my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540703/9423231